# ML estimation - properties of mixed stationary non-stationary process

Tags: maximum-likelihood, normality-assumption, state-space-models, consistency

i try to estimate the following state space model:

Measurement equation
y(t) = a(t) + b(t)

Transition equations
a(t) = a(t-1) + e(t)
b(t) = C*b(t-1) + u(t)

where the observations y(t) are decomposed into a persistent component a(t) and a transitory component b(t). C is the parameter of interest.

My transition matrix consists of a unit root (due to the random walk a(t)) and an estimated parameter C.

Is this feasible? Because often the literature states, that there should be no unknown parameters (such as C), when the transition matrix contain unit roots.
But some literature states that this is feasible, when the determinant of I-TL can be factorised into two polynomials B(L)A(L), where B(L) contain no unit roots and A(L) contain no unknown paramters. (I=identity matrix, L=Lag Operator)

How is the situation in my example? Can i achieve consistency and/or normality of the parameters asymptotically?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards from Germany.
Johannes